# Jsoup bug when parsing RSS?

Tags: java, rss, jsoup

I'm trying to grab a list of links to articles from this feed:

http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml

However, when Jsoup reads it in, the links in the tags `<link>http://www.cbc.ca/news/?cmp=rss</link>` become `<link />http://www.cbc.ca/news/?cmp=rss`

Ie the tag self closes and if I do

```
Elements items = doc.select("link");
```

it doesn't grab any of the links.

Comment: I couldn't even get JSoup to handle rss feeds. It gives me `Unhandled content type application/rss+xml; charset=iso-8859-1`. The org.w3c.dom and org.xml.sax parsers work fine though.

Answer (score 5):

JSoup is a HTML parser, in HTML the `link` element is defined to have an empty content model. The url you gave seems to contain valid xml, so why don't you try an actual xml parser or a feed parser library like [rome](http://java.net/projects/rome/)?

**Edit:** To extract links from the file using JDK's Xpath implementation you can use code like the following:

```
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
InputSource is = new InputSource("http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xp.evaluate("//link", is, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i=0, len=nodes.getLength(); i<len; i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    String link = node.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(link);
}
```

Comment: so does that mean that I can not capture random tags with `doc.select("myRandomTagName");` ?

Comment: On HTML files you usually can, on arbitrary files that use elements with different semantics from HTML it seems you can't. See my edit for an alternative solution.